# Como sempre mostrar campo de busca

Tags: css

Possuo um formulário onde tenho um campo de busca, esse campo só fica visível quando o usuário clica na imagem da lupa existente e o campo é exibido uma linha abaixo do meu layout, gostaria de deixar o mesmo sempre visível e ao lado do ícone da lupa, fiz algumas modificações mas nada de obter sucesso no que preciso.

O que fiz foi isso, deixei o campo de busca visível:

```
.navbar .search-form {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
z-index: 20;
float: right;
display: block;
top: 40px;
```

}

E tentei alterar a posição alterando a posição do mesmo, tentando posiciona-lo mais acima, sem sucesso.

o código do formulário é esse:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
      <!-- Stat Search -->
      <div class="search-side"> <a href="#" class="show-search"><i class="icon-search-1"></i></a>
        <div class="search-form">
          <form autocomplete="off" role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="#">
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Buscar...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Fim da Busca --> 
      <!-- Início Links Superiores -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="catalogos.php">catálogos e manuais</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="cores.php">cores e linha</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="garantia.php">garantia e uso</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Fim Links Superiores --> 
    </div>
```

O css do mesmo é esse:

```
.search-side {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 19px;
    right: -15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.show-search {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.show-search i {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    display: block;
    color: #aaa;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.show-search:hover i {
    color: #000;
}

/* Campo de Busca*/
.navbar .search-form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
}

.navbar .search-form:before {
    background-color: #ccc;
    top: -2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar .search-form form input {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    z-index: 22;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar .search-form form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

A imagem da página é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu resultado não será obtido, pois eles estão com a propriedade `position` definida como `absolute`.

Mas o que significa?

Significa que, em relação à div "pai" ela tera um posicionamento absoluto com uma distancia de X px do topo e Y px da lateral, por isso está sempre aparecendo abaixo do ícone da lupa. O `css` que está causando esse problema é este aqui:

```
.navbar .search-form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Veja esse [meu fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucvscff0/1/) onde fiz com o resultado que você deseja.

Para resolver o seu problema, você pode definir a div que engloba o ícone de busca e o input do form, com `display:inline-block` para que ela tenha a largura dos dois blocos, e não a largura total da div pai.

Depois faça a mesma definição de inline-block para cada um dos dois elementos, o ícone da lupa (ou no meu exemplo, a 'busca') e o input do formulário.

O importante é lembrar de remover o `position:absolute` pois é ele que está causando o problema.

Comment: Olá @CelsonTrindade, valeu pela grande ajuda, acabei de fazer a manutenção e a dica funcionou perfeitamente, novamente obrigado.

Comment: Não por isso! Fico feliz em ajudar :D